# Cointegration for forex using ARMA model to forecast the spread

Tags: time-series, fx, backtesting, cointegration, stationarity

I am working on an automatized quantitative strategy that use cointegration in Forex. I am backtesting this strategy in Python.

Please see below the python file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1AEYFPAAAE6eW5XeHlkTXprVUU/view?usp=sharing

See below the data that I used to backtest:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1AEYFPAAAE6amx0RWI1MGh3SW8/view?usp=sharing

**My Algorithm is:**

- Read File
- Transform the data with the log return
- Treat Outliers
- Realize the linear regression
- Test for cointegration with ADF test
- If the spread is stationary then apply the best ARMA model
- Forecast and using beta calculation to control the risk

The equity curve of this strategy is:
[image: Equity Curve of Cointegration Strategy]

Could you please help to understand how can I improve this algo?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't your cointegration basically already contained in the AUD/NZD time series?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my opinion this is not the same, because I am not forecasting the price directly but the log return of each currency. Then I multiplied NZDUSD by a coefficient. It this coefficient is 1, then I am forecasting AUD/NZD but if it is not then I am building a new time series.